# Web App is listed on android and not on iOS

Tags: android, ios, facebook, web

Facebook apps listed on Web and Android but not on iOS.

Process

1. Created a App type "Web" from developers.facebook.com
2. Successfully added this app to my "APPS" section on left side of my newsfeed page.(Listed on "APPS")
3. Successfully added this app to my "APPS" section on Android when I logged in with Android's Facebook App. It was automatically added when I logged in on Android.
4. Failed to see this app on any of iOS Facebook App.
   It's not on "APPS" list but it exists on setting->app from iOS.
   There's no menu that I can select this app to be added on Apps list.

It seems like the app doesn't want to be listed on iOS's Facebook app.
Does anyone know how to list the app on my app panel.

Please let me know if I need to clarify this problem.
I've been looking for clues but didn't get lucky and it's driving me crazy.

On iOS, even see all doesn't show the app I created.
On web and android, it works great.

[image]

[image: developer.facebook.com app setting]

Answer (score 0):

This app will only appear in the nav within the Facebook iOS app if your app has been enabled for iOS in your Facebook app dashboard - i.e. you have a native iSO version of your app.

Comment: but the thing is that app is listed automatically on Android not in iOS? No, I didn't enable it for iOS since it's not native app. I didn't enable for Android either but it's listed automatically on Android devices. Am I missing or misunderstood something?